# Is it possible to prevent packet capturing on Android for sent TCP/IP packets?

Tags: android, packet

I'd like to know if some measure is possible to prevent the capturing of packets that are being sent on Android.

I'd need the solution to work via code (cannot rely on external tools).

Packets are already encrypted, but it would be a nice plus if they couldn't be captured, or, at least, that it would be difficult to.

Is anything like this possible or is there no way to prevent capture of a packet via packet capture software?

Comment: How similar to Wireshark do you mean? You can transfer data through audio (I think most phones have a speaker and microphone, but don't quote me on that), but it would be pretty trivial to make a tool to listen in on it.

Comment: @user, no it's data that must be sent to a server computer,have to stick to TCP/IP packets.

Comment: Is rooting the phone enough of a barrier? Once you have root access, you have access to everything. But you could prevent packet capture on a unrooted phone.

Comment: @schroeder,  if at least it can be prevented in unrooted phones, it's better than nothing. We are considering to maybe avoid using the app to rooted phones, anyway.

Comment: @schroeder, I just installed one, and it even says that no root is needed when starting it (at least for that one).

Comment: Root access can be hidden using certain programs (and capturing packets on the access point is impossible to prevent). And your program can probably be reverse engineered to disable the 'prevent packet capture' logic.

Comment: If data is encrypted, why do you care about user capturing the packets?

Answer (score 3):

It's literally impossible.

You can't stop someone from capturing packets once they're handed over from the Android system to the next hop in the network. If you somehow manage to prohibit someone from capturing on the phone, they can still capture on their wifi.

Furthermore, trying to stop it on the phone is just silly. Any determined attacker will spend three minutes setting up a capture on their wifi.

It's simply a function of how TCP/IP works.

> Trying to prevent using the Wi-Fi isn't going to prevent someone else somewhere on the network from capturing or inspecting it. Making users' lives difficult for this reason is security theatre and will only serve to waste people's time and irritate people. You always have to assume the network is untrusted and that everybody can see and intercept your packets.

From comment by [bk2204](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/242928/bk2204).

This is *universally* true. What ever you are trying to achieve, you're doing it the wrong way.

Comment: We can forbid using wifi, that was thought, anyway no possible way to not capture it in phone, right?

Comment: OK, so I have to decompile your app. Or set up a private cell using SDR. Whatever you're planning sounds like security through obscurity. That doesn't work. If data is encrypted, why do you care about who sees your packets?

Comment: @bkk2204, I don't care about other people seeing packets on thw network. What I want to avoid is user intercepting packets in his own phone and changing to other ones he desires.

Comment: @user2638180 "*user intercepting packets in his own phone and **changing to other ones he desires***" I feel this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) and the core of the issue, but not this question is really about. I guess what you really want to do is preventing [replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)? Considering that the request is already encrypted, it'd be more worrying if the user can forge any valid request.

Comment: @Andrew T. Not sure if what I want enters into this type of attack, but what I want is to ensure the integrity of the data transmited, we already take measures, so it can be determined if the data, that is stored in the device, has been modified, if so, it's not sent. Once that is done, it's needed to ensure its integrity when transmited, a good way to do that is to have it encrypted, so the malicious user cannot inmediately know what is being transmitted, and if the packet cannot be changed on the fly, it's even more ensured,  to do that I think it cannot be intercepted while on device.

Comment: @user2638180 Authenticated encryption is enough to protect integrity of data. You don't have to come up with a solution to prevent a user from capturing packets.

Comment: @defalt, just wanted to improve security if possible. After all user may always be able to get the key.

Comment: @user2638180 yes - but trying to stop captures is purely security theater. It doesn't add any real security.

Comment: @user2638180 User won't be able to get the key by packet capture. It requires root and code injection. You can prevent your web service to serve client app on rooted device using SafetyNet.